# Can an AWS AMI name be set during import

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, import

I am trying to import an OVA into AWS using the aws CLI. To do this I run the following command:

```
aws ec2 import-image import-image --client-token 653151442415980 --disk-containers '[{"UserBucket":{"S3Key":"my.ova","S3Bucket":"my bucket"},"Description":"my import"}]' --platform 'Linux'
```

When I do this, I get an AMI name like "ami-import-sfwerwf". I really need this to be more descriptive in the name, so this doesn't work well for me.

Ideally, I could specify the name on import, but changing it after the import is complete would work too. I would really like to avoid having to create an instance and then save it as an AMI afterwards.

Comment: How did you get a value to use for `--client-token`?

Comment: The token just has to be unique for the life of the import. In my case, I concatenated the PID of my script and the current unix time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way that I can find to do this is to do an `image-copy` after the import. The `image-copy` command takes name and description parameters, which will then be given to the copy.

```
aws ec2 copy-image --source-image-id ami-123de3 --source-region us-east-1 --region us-east-1 --name <new-name> --description <description>
```

After that completes successfully, then you can remove the original with:

```
aws ec2 deregister-image --image-id ami-123de3
```

Answer (score 0):

EC2 AMI IDs are randomly-generated. If you need a human-readable label, just use the `--description` option when importing the image.

Comment: I believe the op is asking about the AMI Name, which is different to the AMI ID.